# Can't read value from yml file when testing

Tags: java

This is my main class, when I create a mock class to test the start() function, I got error at ClientSecretBasic line, it said "The value must not be null or empty string
", when I changed the value to constant, it works, that means I didn't get the value from yml file, how to resolve this issue?

```
@Component
public class GrpcAuthorizationInterceptor
 @Value("${configuration.clientId}")
    private String clientId;
    @Value("${configuration.clientSecret}")
    private String clientSecret;

@Override
            public <ReqT, RespT> ClientCall<ReqT, RespT> interceptCall(
                final MethodDescriptor<ReqT, RespT> method, CallOptions callOptions, final Channel next) {
                return new ForwardingClientCall.SimpleForwardingClientCall<>(next.newCall(method, callOptions)) {
                    @Override
                    public void start(Listener<RespT> responseListener, Metadata headers) {
                        ClientSecretBasic clientSecretBasic =  new ClientSecretBasic(new ClientID(clientId), new Secret(clientSecret)); //java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The value must not be null or empty string

                        ***
                    }
                };
            }
}
```

This is my yml file.

```
configuration:
    clientId: "1234"
    clientSecret: "1234"
```

This is how I test it

```
Metadata headers = new Metadata();
        ClientCall.Listener listener = mock(ClientCall.Listener.class);
        clientCall.start(listener, headers);
```

Comment: Which runner are you using for unit testing at RunWith annotation ?

Comment: @SKumar I didn't use any runner, which one should I go with?

Comment: Try with `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)`

Comment: not sure why isn't working..

Comment: Can you post your unit test code showing how are your test creates instance of `GrpcAuthorizationInterceptor` ?

Comment: I created like this      
  ClientInterceptor interceptor = (ClientInterceptor) new GrpcAuthorizationInterceptor();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Spring values can be injected like below

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class SomeTest {
  ClientInterceptor interceptor = (ClientInterceptor) new GrpcAuthorizationInterceptor(); 
 
  @Before
  public void setup() {
       // inject spring property values
       ReflectionTestUtils.setField(interceptor, "clientId", "some-value");
       ReflectionTestUtils.setField(interceptor, "clientSecret", "some-value");

  }
.....
-- test methods
}
```